# onMessageReceived() of extended FirebaseMessagingService is called to late

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, remote-notifications

I followed the instructions provided by google (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) to receive notifications. My application is using two different push notification frameworks and everything is working fine. One of those two frameworks isn't providing any channel id. So I have overwritten onMessageReceived() to intercept the remote message and generate my own notification with the right channel. This is working also.

Here comes my problem: onMessageReceived() is called after the notification is shown! So I always get two notifications. At first I receive the remote message and after that my generated notification is shown! If I put the debugger in between and stop in onMessageReceived() the first message has already arrived in the notification bar. Any ideas?

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty().let {  
             sendNotification(remoteMessage)
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        // generate my own notification
    }
}
```

Yes, service is registered in Manifest, method is always called, message is "Data" and "Notification" is null.

Comment: Can you elaborate on - "My application is using two different push notification frameworks". And also post the payload you are sending FCM.

Comment: One of my frameworks was OneSignal. OneSignal intercepted the messages and that was my failure. If someone has the same problem, he can look at the following part of the documentation: (https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#section-notification-extender-service)

Comment: Were you able to fix this?